# Ember .observe() returns callback twice when used with query-params

Tags: ember.js, observers, query-string

http://jsbin.com/vowup/2

If I click change to random, program logs in console twice.

For some strange reason it works ok when setting revision variable to string, but logs twice for number or any other kind of variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this and the answer will become clear:

```
  toggleHistory: (function() {
    console.log(this.get("revision"));
  }).observes("revision")
```

You will see output like:

```
0.7038348997011781
"0.7038348997011781"
```

Your numbers are being coerced to strings. That is caused by this line:

```
queryParams: ["revision"]
```

Query system is listening to changes and converting every new value into string, so it could appear as part of the URL. That's why you get two changed events.

Comment: Isn't it a bug ? Query system could convert it to string, write to URL, but not overwrite the original

Comment: Implementation detail. In most cases like this, the changed handlers keep calling each other until they all 'agree' on the new value, causing the chain reaction to stop. I presume it would'n be trivial for one part of it to agree on one value, but privately keep another.

Comment: This helped me solve a problem with liquid-fire modals, thanks!