# Ember observes when using queryParams calls back three times on certain values

Tags: ember.js, query-string

I've been playing with the new query parameter feature in ember.js and quite like it. I'm puzzled by how the ember 'observes' works with it. It might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823343/ember-observe-returns-callback-twice-when-used-with-query-params/23839262#23839262), but I think my question is also a bit different.

In [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tosun/5/), I can change the chart type using the dropdown menu, and the changed chart type is displayed in the URL. It all works fine until I type other text for the URL's parameter value, such as "xyz". According to my code, the incorrect chart type string should just be ignored by the app. In the console I see the 'observes' function runs three times, and the query parameter value is changed to 'undefined'. Any clue why this might happen?

Bryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit:

```
    {{view Ember.Select viewName="select"
                content=chartTypes
                prompt="Type:"
                value=selectedChartType}}
```

Reason for that is that it is two-way binding. Ant change to the select is going to reflect your controller/model (depends on which you bound it to).

What is happening in this selected case:

1. You're modifying URL (Value: `QWERTY`)
2. Ember tries to set Ember.Select value to `QWERTY`, but it fails (`QWERTY` is not in the Ember.Select)
3. Since `QWERTY` is not found in Ember.Select it is set to `undefined`
4. Change to `undefined` is reflected on Controller/URL
5. URLs consists of strings, not undefined, thus casting `undefine` into `"undefine"`
6. Last iteration is run with `"undefined"`

Thus you have exactly 3 iterations:

1. Because Ember.Select has not been found
2. Because undefined type cannot be put in URL
3. The last, resolved one

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and has been driving me nuts all morning. Is there a good solution to this? Is there an ember issue that talks through this?

Comment: For those that find this via google, you can work around this by using `Ember.run.scheduleOnce` to apply any updates to value binded properties that are also query params inside the `afterRender` queue. That seems to do the trick.

Comment: Another solution is to omit the `prompt` binding, and manually add it as an option with the value set to your default value