# Liquid Fire Modal Odd Effect or Open/Close/Open?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using liquid-fire to open a modal window in Ember.js. I have almost two identical sections – route, controller and template all extremely similar, but for some reason that I have not been able to debug, one section is producing a peculiar visual effect, almost as though the modal is opening, closing and then re-opening.

http://staging.ckdu.ca/shows
http://staging.ckdu.ca/schedule

Wondering if anyone has seen anything similar to this and might have any advice.

This is what the code looks like:

router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.modal('show-modal', {withParams: ['show_id'], otherParams: 'show'});
  this.resource('schedule', function () {});
});
```

application controller.js:

```
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['show_id'],
  show_id: null
});
```

schedule/index/controller.js:

```
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  filteringByCategory: null,
  init: function() {
    var show_id = this.get('controllers.application').get('show_id');
    if (show_id !== null) { this.setShow(show_id); }
    this._super();
  },
    setShow: function (show_id) {
        if (show_id !== null) {
            var app = this.get('controllers.application');     
            var show = this.store.find('show', show_id);       
        app.set('show_id', show_id);
            app.set('show', show);
        }
        return false;
    },
    actions: {
    openShowModal: function (show_id) {
        this.setShow(show_id);
        return false;
    }
    }
});
```

schedule/index/route.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () { return this.store.all('time_slot'); },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
      controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

schedule/index/template.hbs:

```
<div {{action 'openShowModal' slot.show_id}}>
```

transitions.js:

```
export default function() {

  var duration = 100;

  this.transition(
    this.use('fade', {duration: duration}),
    this.reverse('fade', {duration: duration})
  );

  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('shows.index'),
    this.toRoute('shows.show'),
    this.use('scrollThen', 'toLeft', {duration: duration}),
    this.reverse('scrollThen', 'toRight')
  );

}
```

Comment: what are your transition rules?

Comment: @runspired I've updated my question with the salient parts of transition file.

Comment: I see you've opened up an issue on Github, given what you've posted here and poking around on your site, there's some sort of a rule conflict happening that is unexpected.  It might be because the queryParam is on a different route's controller that more than one transition / rule becomes correct.

Comment: You mean in the transitions file? I tried experimenting with that by stripping out transitions to no success. But perhaps I need to try moving the queryParams into both controllers and with separate modal routes based on your comment.

Comment: Curiously, I tried moving the modal in the route file specifically to the schedule scope, insuring that there was nothing shared between the two, using different query params and had no success. I gave up on that and in the process of returning to my original setup I somehow have ended up at a situation where the both modals are now working but neither queryParams are working in the URL, which seems suggestive. And then as soon as I put the query parameter back on the application controller, the problem returns.

Comment: Also perhaps worthy of mentioning is that this is on liquid fire master with ember 1.11.0-beta.4. I've been reading over the liquid-fire docs thinking perhaps I can customize the modal transition, wondering if I could get a sense of what's happening visually eg by slowing down the animation, but the docs seem to have changed re modal custom transitions.

Comment: I've been adding console info messages to liquid fire and can see that for some reason which I am unable to discover, liquid fire is looping back to modal => observerForParam, and then modal => update
This is console output: shows (working): http://bit.ly/1N2hZLO versus  schedule (problem): http://bit.ly/1IfMT2q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out with help from this [Ember Observe Returns Callback Twice When Used With Query Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823343/ember-observe-returns-callback-twice-when-used-with-query-params).

The salient point is that Ember query params, according to that Stack Overflow answer above, are converted to strings.

My shows section was accessing the Show model, and this model was using the default id attribute, where my schedule section was using a TimeSlot model, which had an attribute for show ids that I had set manually as DS.attr('number').

So for my schedule section, I was setting the query param, which changed it once – and liquid-fire observed that change and started its process – and then that queryParam was converted to a string, which changed it a second time – and liquid-fire observed that change as well, and interrupted itself, etc.

At any rate, thanks @runspired for your help with this.